# Google maps API Animate polygon color change

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found [this great sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dynamic) from Google about making polygons become colorful on mouse hover.

What I need is to make a polygon over a number of countries, for example: USA, Canada, and Mexico, and make them animate a color change on hover, animate restoration of the original color on leave, and on click, return country name and zoom in to the country. I already started, but immediately got stuck.

Can anyone help me with this task?

Comment: So, you only need help with the animation part? Because that seems like a simple CSS related thing.

Comment: Also with making a polygon over a country...

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I got stuck right away...

Comment: Specifics, what did you try? How did you get stuck? Show us your code.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this example from the FusionTables documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/mouseover_map_styles)?

Comment: Not only that....

Comment: Well, perhaps that will get you "unstuck"...

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a little too late but for anyone else having same question:

```
    (function(){
        var opacityUp =true;
        var animOpacity = 0.1;
        var animStep = 0.005;
        function animatePolygons() {
            if(opacityUp) {
                animOpacity+=animStep;
                if(animOpacity>=0.99) {
                    opacityUp = false;
                }
            } else {
                animOpacity-=animStep;
                if(animOpacity<=0.1) {
                    opacityUp = true;
                }
            }
                polygon.setOptions({
                    fillOpacity: animOpacity
                });
            requestAnimationFrame(animatePolygons);
        };
        animatePolygons();
    })();
```